# Avoid switch statement in Jbehave steps

Tags: java, oop, switch-statement, jbehave

I'm working on jbehave scenario. My step uses switch statement.
There could be plenty of such tabs. 
It means everytime I have to add another case statement.

How can I replace the switch statements with OOP?

Now I distinguish the tab by enum, as only string can be received from jbehave.

But I believe there is more elegant way.

> When I open publication in Editor and go to Audience tab

```
@When("I open publication in Editor and go to $tab tab")
public void openEditorAndGoToTab(String tab){

    TaggingUiTabs enumTab = EnumTextMatcher.matchEnum(tab, 
    TaggingUiTabs.getAllTabs());

    editorWindow.goToTaggingUi();
    switch (enumTab){
        case AUDIENCE:
            taggingUi.goToAudienceTab();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The simple answer would be to make each different case a class that implements a interface with methods like `goToTab`, then you just call the class method instead of manually dispatching. Without more context though, idk if you'll be able to get more in depth suggestions.

Comment: JBhehave can automatically convert input parameters to any Enum type

Answer (score 1):

I have sometimes used a Map to avoid very long switches, e.g. like this:

```
private final Map<TaggingUiTabs, Runnable> actionMap;

public MyStepsClass() {
   actionMap.put(TaggingUiTabs.AUDIENCE, () -> taggingUi.goToAudienceTab());
   actionMap.put(TaggingUiTabs.OTHER_TAB, () -> taggingUi.goToOtherTab());
}

@When("I open publication in Editor and go to $tab tab")
public void openEditorAndGoToTab(String tab){

    TaggingUiTabs enumTab = EnumTextMatcher.matchEnum(tab, 
    TaggingUiTabs.getAllTabs());

    editorWindow.goToTaggingUi();
    actionMap.get(enumTab).run();
}
```

This way I can easily add more actions. I find it very useful whenever I cannot redesign the rest of the code to be more object-oriented.